# How to estimate such type of series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $p \in(0,1)$ and series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{n^2}{k} p^{n^2 -k}(1-p)^{k}$.

What is a best way to estimate behaviour of this function such type of sums in term of $p$ and $n$? Actually I'm interested in $p = f(n)$, for which this series goes to $1$ with $n$ goes to infinity.

Maybe it's looks strange but I meet this problem in my probability task. Also, maybe there is some ideas for general case ($m \in \mathbb{N}$ instead of $2n-1$)?

Comment: By the binomial theorem,  it would be bounded by $1$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster yes, I understand , but there are have no at least $(n-1)^2$ terms. So this estimate isn't good.

Comment: Do you enjoy hypergeometric functions ? If you do, just tell.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it will be great even in hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

From a probabilistic point of view, we could view this sum as $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq 2n-1)$ with $X_n\sim \text{Bin}(n^2,p)$. Now, as $n$ grows, its expectation $p n^2$ grows with the square of $n$ and the standard deviation $n\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ grows with the order $n$. This already gives us an indication that $X_n$ should grow as a stochastic sequence with the order $n^2$. In particular, we have by the central limit theorem
$$ \frac{X_n - pn^2}{n\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1) $$
Now, we can calculate our probability as $n$ tends to infinity
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq 2n-1) = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_n - pn^2}{n\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\leq \frac{2n-1 - pn^2}{n\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq \frac{2-1/n - p n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right) $$
As $n$ grows, the right hand within the probability tends to $-\infty$ and thus as expected, the overall probability will tend to $0$. To be precise, we can estimate this using upper-tail-inequalities provided $pn + 1/n > 2$.
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq \frac{2-1/n - p n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right) \leq \frac{\exp\left(-\left(\frac{p n + 1/n - 2}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right)^2/2\right)}{\frac{p n + 1/n - 2}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\cdot\sqrt{2}} $$
This method relies on how well the binomial distribution is estimated with the normal distribution. I am sure this goes perfectly fine. However, if you need a rigorous proof you have to think about how quick this converges and if we can upper bound this convergence. However, I'll just limit my answer to the main part of your question.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

**EDIT**: This method gives a good approximation of the series as $n$ grows. However, I am not quite sure if it is an underestimation or overestimation due to the convergence rate (I have not given this a thought, so it might be fairly easy to solve). However, if you are not satisfied, try to look into Chebyshev's or Markov's inequality which do not depend on normal distributions. Obviously they are a bit less tight but they don't depend on the Gaussian approximation and they will give you (with $100\%$ certainty) upper bounds.

Comment: You've said that with $n$ grows the probability goes to zero. But what will be if $p$ depends of $n$? I guess it may become goes to one

Comment: Good question which is easily answered. I will just focus here on the intuition part of my question which can be made rigorous using the same methods. So, the expectation is now $p_n n^2$ and if we assume $p_n\to0$ the standard deviation will be asymptotically equal to $n\sqrt{p_n}$. Using these things and to make this a bit interactive, I'd like you to answer my question: what do you think happens when you let a) $p_n=1/n^2$, b) $p_n = 1/n$, c) $p=\min\{1,3/n\}$?

Comment: I guess that's is not good to estimate this sum by right part? The RHS may goes to $1$ , but the left one may goes to zero at the same moment.

Comment: If I am correct, you are saying that at one point you have $a<b$ and $b$ goes to $1$, hence we cannot conclude anything about $a$. However, you don't need this. I gave an estimate of the probability but as $n$ tends to infinity you can just calculate whether or not this probability converges to $1$ or $0$ if that makes sense. I gave the estimate because I thought you wanted to know how quick it converges

Comment: Have you already tried to solve my question?

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but just the result from a CAS.*

Considering

$$S_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n^2}{k}\, p^{n^2 -k}\,(1-p)^{k}$$ a CAS gives as a result
$$S_m=1-\binom{n^2}{m+1} (1-p)^{m+1}\, p^{n^2-m-1} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,-n^2+m+1;m+2;\frac{p-1}p\right)$$ where appears [the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).